# Subject Extraction of a paragraph/document using NLP

Tags: python, nlp, n-gram

I am trying to build a subject extractor, simply put, read all the sentences of a paragraph and make a calculated guess to what the subject of the paragraph/article/document is. I *might* even upgrade it to a summerize depending on the progress I make.

There is a great deal of information on the internet. It is difficult to understand all of it and select a correct path, as I am not well versed with NLP.

I was hoping someone with some experience could point me in the right direction.

1. I am NOT looking for a linguistic computation model, but rather an n-gram or neural network approach, something that has been done recently.
2. I am also looking into coreference resolution using n-grams, if anyone has any leads on that, it is much appreciated. Slightly familiar with the Stanford Coreferential Solver, but don't want to use it as is.

Any information, ideas and opinions are welcome.

Comment: Are you looking for the "subject" which will be unique to each sentence or the "topic" of the paragraph/document? These are two different items and require different algorithms.

Comment: @AhmedS **"topic"** of the paragraph/document. Won't I need the subject of every sentence to know the topic of the document?

Answer (score 0):

@Dagger,

For finding the 'topic' of the whole document, there are several approaches you can try and research. The unsupervised approaches will be faster and will get you started but may not differentiate between closely related documents that have similar topics. These also don't require neural network. The supervised techniques will be able to recognise differences in similar documents better but require training of networks. You should be able to easily find blogs about implementing these in your desired programming language.

Unsupervised

- K-Means Clustering using TF-IDF On Text Words - [see intro here](http://brandonrose.org/clustering)
- Latent Dirichlet Allocation

Supervised

- Text Classification models using SVM, Logistic Regressions and neural nets
- LSTM/RNN models using neural net

The neural net models will require training on a set of known documents with associated topics first. They are best suited for picking ONE most likely topic from their model but there are multi-class topic implementations possible.

If you post example data and/or domain along with programming language, I can give some more specifics for you to explore.

Comment: Thanks a ton! The domain I am working on is general, nothing specific. Something like news articles, or some books/magzines. Also I am looking to program in python.

Comment: If it's news articles, then try the K-means link in my answer to start with - it's fast and usually OK. Couple of other Python options for neural network supervised learning are: FastText and Spacy. You can also roll your own with Tensorflow if you want more hands on tweaking option for the neural networks.